# Google Cloud Function + Calendar API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use a Google Cloud Function to handle authorization for the google calendar api. But I'm having trouble exchanging the code for a token. I have written two functions, one that generates an auth url that directs users to sign in, with a code and the second is the one that should exchange the code for a token and redirect users to the page. The second function just times out and doesn't return anything.

```js
// The first cloud function
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const credentials = require('./credentials.json')

exports.getURL = async (req, res) => {
    const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];
    let redirectURL, oAuth2Client, response;

    try {
        redirectURL = await authorize(credentials);
    }
    catch (e) {
        // console.log(e.message);
        response = JSON.stringify({
            statusCode: 500,
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              error: e.message,
            }),
        })
        return res.send(response);
    } 
    
    console.log(redirectURL);
    response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      },
      body: redirectURL,
  }
    return res.send(response);

    function authorize(credentials) {
        // const { CLIENT_SECRET, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URIS } = process.env
        const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed
        oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
          client_id,
          client_secret,
          redirect_uris[0]
        );
        return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client);
    }
    
    function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client) {
        const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
          access_type: "offline",
          scope: SCOPES,
        });
      
        // returns link that user clicks to authorize app
        return authUrl;
    }
}
```

The output of the first function is this:

```js
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    },
    "body": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&response_type=code&client_id=92706390722-rl3h6c2cmqqi15m0ou58cva56hp2vo0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-learning-node-291903.cloudfunctions.net%2FgetCalEvents"
}
```

I'm not sure what is happening, but the console log statements, don't output anything useful. Any hints as to where I could be encountering a problem?

```js
// 2nd function that exchanges code for token
exports.getCalEvents = async (req, res) => {
  // wait for an event 
  // request comes in with code parameter and query string from 'GET' request 
  let params = req.query;
  const code = params.code;
  let token, response;

  try {
    token = await getAccessToken(code);
    console.log('token', token);
  } catch (err) {
    response = JSON.stringify({
        statusCode: 500,
      })
    return response;
  }

  async function getAccessToken(code) {
    console.log(code);
    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
    oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id,
        client_secret,
        redirect_uris[2]
    );
    try {
      let accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
      console.log('access token', accessToken);
      return accessToken;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
  //return access token
  response = JSON.stringify({
    statusCode: 302,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    },
    body: {'token': token},
  });

  console.log(response);

  return res.send(response);
}
```

Comment: You say you've written two functions, but I only see one function exported here.  It contains an inner JavaScript function.  How are you invoking this?  Are you saying it logs absolutely nothing?

Comment: Updated with the first function. 
Invoking the function through an http trigger. The inner function should be called at the top, in the try catch block.
It logs the code from the request, just nothing after.

Comment: How are you invoking this function?  What *exactly* are you expecting it to do other than what you observe?  Please edit the question to be clear.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example